# C++ BIO_do_handshake fails, but SSL_connect works

Tags: c++, sockets, openssl

I want to convert TCP socket to BIO socket, so I have initialized OpenSSL library (`SSL_library_init(); SSL_load_error_strings();` etc.) and then create variables and connect it.

```
// .. initialize library
SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "server.crt", NULL);
SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
BIO *bio = BIO_new_socket(socket, BIO_NOCLOSE);   // socket is TCP socket
SSL_set_bio(ssl, bio, bio);
BIO_do_handshake(bio);                 // returns 0 -> connection could not be established
```

I have tried this with `SSL_connect(ssl)` and then write/read with `SSL_write`/`SSL_read` and it works, but I want use `BIO_read`/`BIO_write` and as I said - `BIO_do_handshake` fails and if I still try send data throught BIO socket then my request is unecrypted, but server responses with encrypted data.

So it looks like that handshake on server side is successful, because server knows, that I want communicate encrypted, but my side doesnt know it.

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BIO_f_ssl.html): "*`BIO_do_handshake()` attempts to complete an SSL handshake on the supplied BIO and establish the SSL connection. It returns 1 if the connection was established successfully. **A zero or negative value is returned if the connection could not be established, the call `BIO_should_retry()` should be used for non blocking connect BIOs to determine if the call should be retried**. If an SSL connection has already been established this call has no effect.*"

Comment: Also, try using `BIO_set_ssl()` instead of `SSL_set_bio()`, especially if you want `BIO_read()/BIO_write()` to handle encryption.  And try `BIO_set_ssl_mode()` to put the `bio` into client mode before calling `BIO_do_handshake()`.  Or use `BIO_new_ssl()` or `BIO_new_ssl_connect()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for response, but its not working. I´m not sure with sequence of commands, but everything I have tried was not good way. Can you specify it? And what flag to `BIO_set_ssl()`. Why `BIO_new_ssl()` when I need that my socket, which is connected to server?

Comment: I was suggesting using `BIO_new_ssl()` instead of using `SSL_new()` with `SSL_set_bio()`/`BIO_set_ssl()`. Create a socket `BIO` and an SSL `BIO`, link them together, call `BIO_set_ssl_mode()`, then 
`BIO_do_handshake()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This verbal expression is hardly understandable for me. Could you please write it here as a post with code? Because from your comment I dont know, what you mean with `BIO_new_ssl()`, because it will create new `BIO`, but I need `BIO` from `BIO_new_socket()` and if I should link together these 2 `BIO`s with `SSL_set_bio()` then Im getting `SIGSEGV`. Thank you so much for your responses.